# Load .c File when needed

Tags: c, file, include

Good Morning,

I know that one can use #include "data1.c" in the header to include a specific c-file.
But what if I have a carpet full of dataX.c and want to run one specific when asked.

Is it possible to implement it?

regards!

Comment: Never include .c files. Only include .h files

Comment: No, includes are done during compilation, not during runtime. You can give the variables and functions there different names and decide during runtime which you want to use.

Comment: THX! I think that´s it! :D

Comment: @klutt If these *.c files are automatically generated, it is fine and common practice.

Comment: I managed to do it in another way. passing arguments to main( argc, argv) and inside of the main function there is a switch function.